# Complex numbers focus on the main Argument

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In this quesion we will discuss on the main branch of $Log$. Prove that for all $z\in \Bbb C \setminus ((-\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)) $ :
$$Log(z)+Log(1-z)=Log(z(1-z))$$
My attempt:
its is clear that $Re(Log(z)+Log(1-z))=Re(Log(z(1-z))). $ left to show that $Arg(z)+Arg(1-z)=Arg(z(1-z)).  $so we need to divide it to 3 domains, which means if we mark $z=re^{i x}$, the domains will be:  $$ 0<r<1,-\pi<x<\pi$$ $$ 0<r<\infty,0<x<\pi$$ $$ 0<r<\infty,-\pi<x<0$$
I tried to find a way of calculate $Arg(1-re^{i x}) $ for simplify the proof without any succeed.

Comment: $\log$ has many branches, it is a multivalued function.

Comment: @markvs Indeed, but the OP is talking about the main branch of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{Arg}{Arg}$You are right that this can be done by considering three cases, but it is not necessary to compute $\Arg(1-z)$ explicitly.

$\Arg(z) + \Arg(1-z)$ is *an* argument of $z(1-z)$. It order to show that it is equal to $\Arg(z(1-z))$, it suffices to show that $\Arg(z) + \Arg(1-z)$ is in the range $(-\pi, \pi)$ for all $z$ in the given domain.

**Case 1:** $z$ is in the upper half-plane. Then $1-z$ is in the lower half-plane and
$$
 \Arg(z) \in (0, \pi) \, , \, \Arg(1-z) \in (-\pi, 0) \\
\implies \Arg(z) + \Arg(1-z) \in (-\pi, \pi) \, .
$$

**Case 2:** $z$ is in the lower half-plane. This works similarly as in case 1.

**Case 3:** $z$ is a real number in the interval $(0, 1)$. Then
$$
  \Arg(z) + \Arg(1-z) = 0 + 0 = 0\, .
$$